# How to check first name and last name is in a list of names in Python? Is it possible?

Tags: python, string, list, selenium

The scenario is like this, I'm checking 2 strings in a list, I have a variable containing a string of first name, and a variable containing a last name. And a list containing only strings of their full names. I tried using "and" so that if the first name and the last name are both true we can say that the full name in the list is indeed true, I want them to compare to the list of it's original full name so that it will give me a Boolean value of True. But I'm having problem because if I change either one, it still gives off a result of True. Is my scenario possible? or if not is there any work-around? Here is the idea of the code this doesn't work I just used this to explain my work, I hope this may help to visualize my question.

```
      first_name = 'John Eric'
      last_name = 'Delos Santos'
      list = ['Delos Santos, John Eric', 'Delos Santos, John Eric', 'Delos Santos, John Eric', 'Delos Santos, John Eric', 'Delos Santos, John Eric']


      if last_name and first_name in list:
         print(True)

      else:
         print(False)
```

I would appreciate your kind response, Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example, it looks like a pattern possibility is there in the `list` i.e  `<lastname>, <firstname>`. So you can just search this string in the `list`

Your condition can become

```
if f"{last_name}, {first_name}" in list:
  print(True)
else:
  print(False)
```

If such a pattern isn't consistent, then you can use this to find the result

```
result = next((True for i in list if first_name in i and last_name in i), False)
print(result)
```

This will iterate all the names and check for occurrences of `first_name` and `last_name` in each individual string. If it succeeds, it will return `True`, or else it will fallback to `False` which you can print

Comment: I tried and the second is the nearest solution, but the only problem is, I need that, even with the slightest, alteration in the full_name in list, (i.e,) "Delos antos, John Eric"  it could detect and will print false, also, thank you for your answer. but, do you think there are any ways to do that?

Comment: I don't think there will be a proper way to verify the names if typos exist in the `list`, the best I can think of is comparing individual characters and creating some algorithm out of it based on the data pattern which is there in the `list` but this is a very hacky approach and I would not recommend this at all.

Comment: I see, thank you sir for your insight, you really are a big help!

Comment: if my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the list is always ordered in the same way, so you can do:

```
    first_name = 'John Eric'
    last_name = 'Delos Santos'
    YourList = ['Delos Santos, John Eric', 'Delos Santos, John Eric', 'Delos Santos, John Eric', 'Delos Santos, John Eric', 'Delos Santos, John Eric']
    
    full_name = last_name + ", " + first_name
    
    if full_name in YourList:
         print(True)
    else:
         print(False)
```

If not, please let me know!

Comment: My initial solution was like this, the only problem is that, sometimes, I feed names with suffixes, and pref, like, "Dr." it it gives off a fail reult, thus prone to error. Thank you

Comment: I can't format it like in the code but that's is how did it for the mean time.

Comment: bool_result = []
        for each_name in list:
            full_name = (last_n in each_name) and (first_n in each_name)
            bool_result.append(full_name)
        result = all(elem == True for elem in bool_result)
        self.assertTrue(result)

Comment: since I'm still not good with one liner code, I do understand how MANORIT CHAWDHRY's code works, just a little, I'm sticking with this code for the mean time instead. It somehow detects a little change in the list, but I'm not really tried it with some suffixes and prefixes. And I still not test this further

Comment: Update Again: I simplified my code, so far this give me my desired response. It is almost the same with my previous. Here is the code.

Comment: for each_name in list:
    if last_name in each_name and first_name in each_name:
        print(True)

    else:
        print(False)

Comment: It gives off false, even a slight changes in one of the list, and it gives true even if I add some prefixes and suffixes too. As long as it detects the first name and last name. I hope this may help you.